# Use a function to find common elements in two sequences in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to complete the exercise on page 46 of Apple's new book "The Swift Programming Language".  It gives the following code:

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.GeneratorType.Element: Equatable, T.GeneratorType.Element == U.GeneratorType.Element> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3], [3])
```

The exercise is to change the function so that all elements that both sequences have are returned.  To do this I tried to use the following code:

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.GeneratorType.Element:     Equatable, T.GeneratorType.Element == U.GeneratorType.Element> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> T.GeneratorType[] {
    var toReturn = T.GeneratorType[]()
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                toReturn.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn
}
anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3], [3])
```

But on line 2, I get the error: Could not find the member 'subscript'

What is the reason for this error and what is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I didn't have to ask it myself as I was going through the code myself.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by making the return value an Array of T.GeneratorType.Element.

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U where T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType, T.Generator.Element: Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Array<T.Generator.Element> {
    var toReturn = Array<T.Generator.Element>()
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                toReturn.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn
}
anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3], [3])
```

Comment: Your comment says that you return T.GeneratorType.Element, but it is only returning T.  I am posting my version that corrects this.

Comment: @TimRupe, that was from a suggested edit. Thanks for catching the mistake

Comment: Any idea why var toReturn = Array<T.GeneratorType.Element>() works but var toReturn = [T.GeneratorType.Element]() gives an error?

Comment: This seems to be crashing XCode

Comment: This crashes Xcode 6.0.1, better to use Socrates' array declaration from below: `var toReturn: [T.Generator.Element] = []` to keep things working

Comment: With the current Swift 2 this can be simplified to `return lhs.filter { rhs.contains($0) }`

Answer (score 12):

From Swift 3, **Generator** protocol is renamed **Iterator** protocol : [(link to github proposal)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md)

So, the function need to be written:

```
func commonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
        var common: [T.Iterator.Element] = []

        for lhsItem in lhs {
            for rhsItem in rhs {
                if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                    common.append(lhsItem)
                }
            }
        }
        return common
}
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer, until apple decides to rename something again w/c seems to be the case on every new release.

Comment: This the updated answer which is in sync with the current Swift syntax.

Answer (score 8):

I had compiler errors with the above two solutions, I am running the guide from the iBook in the Xcode 6.01 playground.  I had consistent compiler complaints about array declarations I found here so I am assuming the posters may be using an earlier version of swift.  If I'm wrong, it would be great to know.

For array declarations, I have found that

```
    var thingList : [ThingType] = []
```

has worked consistently, so I tended to go with that, forsaking

```
    var thing[],thing[]()  // gave compiler errors/warnings
```

My environment never was able to resolve a thing called *T.GeneratorType[.Element]*

The solution I came up for this experiment is

---

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U
                    where
                    T: SequenceType, U: SequenceType,
                    T.Generator.Element: Equatable,
                    T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element>
                    (lhs: T, rhs: U)
-> [T.Generator.Element]
{
    var  returnValue: [T.Generator.Element] = []
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
           if lhsItem == rhsItem {
              returnValue.append(lhsItem)
           }
        }
    }
    return returnValue
}

let commonNumberList = anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8], [2,3,9,14,8,21])
println("common Numbers = \(commonNumberList)")

let commonStringList = anyCommonElements(["a","b","c"],["d","e","f","c","b"])
println("common Strings = \(commonStringList)")
```

---

The tutorial text really did not properly prepare me at all to actually solve the experiments without a lot of additional reading. Thanks to everyone here for contributing their solutions, it has really helped me get a great introduction to Swift.

Comment: Only this worked for me. And I agree with having to read up to solve the `Experiments`. But I think that is what they intended too... :)

Answer (score 4):

In the most recent version of Swift (5.1), the following code works:

```
func anyCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> Array<T.Element>
    where T.Element: Equatable, T.Element == U.Element
{
    var templist = Array<T.Element>()
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                templist.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
   return templist
}
anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3], [3])
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to solve this in Swift 3 is using the filter function as follows:

```
func anyCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
        return lhs.filter { rhs.contains($0) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was to define the return value as an array so that was possible to add element to it.

```
func anyCommonElements<T, U where T:SequenceType, U:SequenceType, 
T.Generator.Element: Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element >(lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Array <T.Generator.Element> {
   var result = Array <T.Generator.Element>();
   for lhsItem in lhs {
       for rhsItem in rhs {
          if lhsItem == rhsItem {
            result.append(lhsItem);
          }
       }
  }
  return result;
}

print(anyCommonElements([1,3,7,9,6,8],rhs:[4,6,8]));
```

Comment: I'm flagging this for low quality for the following reasons: code-only answer, no explanation was provided, the code does not compile (Error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";")

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been answered, and the original question was about working with generic arrays, there is a way using `Set` and improving the stackoverflow knowledge base I still want to post it.

The swift class `Set` contains these four methods:

```
Set.union(sequence:)
Set.subtract(sequence:)
Set.intersect(sequence:)
Set.exclusiveOr(sequence:)
```

which are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Set_Structure/index.html

You can convert two arrays into sets and use these methods:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [3, 4]

let set1 = Set<Int>(array1)
let set2 = Set<Int>(array2)

let union = set1.union(set2)                // [2, 3, 1, 4]
let subtract = set1.subtract(set2)          // [2, 1]
let intersect = set1.intersect(set2)        // [3]
let exclusiveOr = set1.exclusiveOr(set2)    // [2, 4, 1]
```

---

*Edit 1:*

Like Martin R mentioned in a comment, the type of `Set<T>` has to inherit the protocol `Hashable`, which is slightly more restrictive than `Equatable`.
And also the order of elements is not preserved, therefore consider the relevance of ordered elements!

Comment: Note that this requires the elements to be `Hashable`, which is slightly more restrictive than `Equatable`. – Also note that this does not preserve the *order* of the elements (which might be relevant or not).

Comment: Added your notes to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Swift 5.6:

```
func anyCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Element]
  where T.Element: Equatable, T.Element == U.Element
{
  var commonElements: [T.Element] = []
  for lhsItem in lhs {
      for rhsItem in rhs {
          if lhsItem == rhsItem {
              commonElements.append(rhsItem)
          }
      }
  }
  return commonElements
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this in a similar style to the given code asked to modify.  I am curious how you know to use T.element though.  I thought you could just add [T].  In the Swift Tour playground, they kind of skip over mentioning what the .Element keyword is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer valid for the latest version of Swift. Here is an update that is compatible with version 3.0.1, they have simplified how to make a generic array.

```
func showCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
        var result:[T.Iterator.Element] = []
        for lhsItem in lhs {
            for rhsItem in rhs {
                if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                    result.append(lhsItem)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
}
```

You can test the code with the following commands:

```
showCommonElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 7, 3])
showCommonElements(["apple", "banana", "orange", "peach"], ["orange", "pear", "apple"])
```

Answer (score 0):

[OrderedSet](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedSet.md) makes this easy, as long as your elements are `Hashable`.

```swift
// [4, 6, 8, 10] as OrderedSet
(1..<13).commonElements(with: stride(from: 4, through: 10, by: 2))
```

```
import Collections

public extension Sequence {
  func commonElements<Sequence: Swift.Sequence>(with sequence: Sequence) -> OrderedSet<Element>
  where Element == Sequence.Element {
    OrderedSet(self).intersection(sequence)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working solution for Swift 5.4:

```
func anyCommonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Element]
    where T.Element: Equatable, T.Element == U.Element
{
    var commonElements = [T.Element]()
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                commonElements.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }
    return commonElements
}
```