# What are the constraints of Swift's array syntax?

Tags: arrays, swift, syntax

I'm working through the exercises in *The Swift Programming Language*, and one thing I noted as odd was the Array syntax.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027426/237904), `Array<T.Generator.Element>()` works, yet `var common = [T.Generator.Element]()` does not. At the same time, `var common: [T.Generator.Element] = []` is correct.

What are the rules around the Array syntax/initialization? Why doesn't the second line work?

Comment: The rules are: the swift compiler does what it does, and sometimes when it does something odd and inconsistent, like in this case, it’s a bug and you should file a radar :)