# Swift: Cannot create empty array of nested enum type

Tags: swift

I am trying to declare an empty array of enum defined inside of another class as follows, and am getting the following error:

```
class OuterClass {
    enum MyEnum {
        case ThingOne
        case ThingTwo
    }
}

// Error: Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[OuterClass.MyEnum.Type]'
var emptyEnumArray = [OuterClass.MyEnum]()
emptyEnumArray.append(.ThingOne)
```

However, I can declare the array as follows with no problem:

```
// No errors
var emptyEnumArray: [OuterClass.MyEnum] = []
```

This only appears to be an issue when the enum is defined inside of another class, as this works:

```
enum OtherEnum {
    case ThingOne
    case ThingTwo
}

var emptyArrayTwo = [OtherEnum]()
emptyArrayTwo.append(.ThingTwo)
```

Any thoughts on why the first snippet doesn't work? Is this a language bug?

Comment: looked at it myself, and seems a lot like a bug yes. Have you tried running it with compiler warnings turned off?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a Swift bug right now. This also works.

```
var emptyEnumArray = Array<OuterClass.MyEnum>()
```

The question just recalls me to [a question in apple Swift tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027271/use-a-function-to-find-common-elements-in-two-sequences-in-swift).