# Swift cannot create array of tuples containing a nested type

Tags: swift, nested-types

I'm trying to do something that *should* be possible, but I'm getting a strange error. I have a nested type `Gravl.Node` and am trying to instantiate an array of tuples like so:

```
var attributes = [(attribute: String?, value: Gravl.Node)]()
```

…but Swift is complaining:

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[(attribute: String?.Type, value: Gravl.Node.Type)]'

Any idea what gives? If I replace the nested type with something else it works fine.

Is this a bug in the parser/compiler?

Comment: That's a bug, compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833078/swift-cannot-create-empty-array-of-nested-enum-type.

Comment: Workaround: `typealias Gravl_Node = Gravl.Node`, `var attributes = [(attribute: String?, value: Gravl_Node)]()`

Comment: @vacawama Aha, I didn't think to try a typealias, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug as noted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32833078/1630618).

Following the example of that Q & A, you can change the syntax of the way you create the array:

```
var attributes: [(attribute: String?, value: Gravl.Node)] = []
```

or

```
var attributes = Array<(attribute: String?, value: Gravl.Node)>()
```

---

In this case, you can also work around the issue by creating a `typealias`:

Example:

```
class Gravl {
    enum Node {
        case first, last
    }
}

typealias Gravl_Node = Gravl.Node  // work around Swift bug
var attributes = [(attribute: String?, value: Gravl_Node)]()

attributes.append((attribute: "hello", value: Gravl.Node.first))
```